# How to automatically kill a logstash agent when tests are done?

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash agent that monitors our automatic tests' log dumps -

at the beginning of each bulk of tests, an agent is started, listens to a specific folder, and at the end it should stop.

The problem is at the end - i need to somehow signal the logstash agent that the tests are done and kill itself..

How can I do that? 
What is the way to configure the agent so that when it sees a certain log message from the tests it kills himself?

My config file:

```
input {

  file {
    type => "cloudify-logs"
    path => "<path_to_test_class_folder>/*"
    tags => [ "<suite_name>" , "<test_name>" , "<build_number>" , "<version>" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  redis { host => "<host>" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

Comment: How do you start logstash?

Comment: with this:
java -jar logstash-1.1.13.jar agent -f logstash-shipper.conf -l logstash-shipper-log.txt&

Comment: Try to use java-service-wrapper: http://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/java-service-wrapper-or-how-to-daemonize-your-java-services-for-all-major-oses/ instead your approach

Comment: I was thinking of using a custom filter that would do the detection and execute System.exit()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552053/how-to-return-to-terminal-when-logstash-filter-get-eof/31569955#31569955

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to put a line at the end of your log such as:

```
END TEST
```

You can then create a LogStash "kill" script which is executed by LogStash when it hits that line.

For example:

```
filter
{
    if [message] =~ "^END TEST"
    {
        mutate
        {
            add_tag => ["end"]
        }
    }
}

output
{
    if "end" in [tags]
    {
        exec
        {
            command => "kill_logstash.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine. A proper way to kill the LogStash agent is to use the LogStash exit plugin: https://github.com/arey/logstash-exit-plugin
`if "endfile" in [tags] {
   exit {
      pause_second => 10
      exit_code => 0
   }
}`