# How to return to terminal when logstash filter get eof?

Tags: filter, logstash, eof

Now when logstash filter get eof, it seems that logstash filter is running yet, but file doesn't have more logs to output to elasticsearch index.

How can i get out of logstash filter when it's the end of file (eof), to do another tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve the problem using exec on output of logstash filter, and create a bash script to kill logstash process.

In logstash filter:

```
   input
   {
      ...
   }
   filter
   {
      ...
   }
   output
   {
     exec
    {
        command => "sh kill_logstash.sh"
    }
     ...
   }
```

In bash script (kill_logstash.sh):

```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo 'Terminou a leitura do ficheiro'
   pkill -f  logstash
   exit 0
```

Same Problem: [How to automatically kill a logstash agent when tests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299337/how-to-automatically-kill-a-logstash-agent-when-tests-are-done)

Comment: ` error: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/exec"`

Answer (score 1):

there is no concept of eof in logstash. logstash continuous monitor input file . if any change happen in file it will send to filter .
if you want to monitor multiple file than you can give multiple files block in input section.